# Find out which access point devices are connected to

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dhcp, arp

I work in a school and we have a multitude of access points dotted around the site. We have an open WiFi connection throughout that is locked down using a mac address filter.

We are currently having to delete lots of unknown leases from the DHCP, day after day, as they are all currently being taken up whenever the kids come into school. We clearly have an access point not configured correctly somewhere and the kids are able to connect to it.

My question is:

Is there any way I can backtrack a DHCP lease request to a specific access point or send an ARP request from an access point (only getting ARP responses from devices connected to the access point and not from the entire network).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It would help to know a little more about your network. I'm guessing your APs are not a set of enterprise-class APs, otherwise you would've just looked at your management software for the answer to this question. Is the backhaul of the Wi-Fi network just one single Ethernet [V]LAN, or is it multiple [V]LANs with multiple IP subnets? Do you have managed switches everywhere, or do you have a lot of unmanaged switches? Where is the MAC address filter applied? Do you set the same MAC address filter list on each AP by hand, or is there a central device that enforces the filter?

Comment: When you say you have to delete a lot of leases, are these real leases or just IP addresses the DHCP server has decided it can't serve out because it already detected machines squatting on those address?

Answer (score 0):

If you have managed switches, you can usually look at the management UI for the switches to see a list of which MAC addresses have been seen out which port. So look at the DHCP server, find a lease given to a MAC address (DHCP Client ID) that's not on your MAC address whitelist, then log into your switches and see which port that MAC address is on. Then track down where that switch port is patched to, and see what's plugged into it.